# can iOS openURL of tel without alertView?

Tags: ios

We can use the `telprompt:// URL` scheme to open a phone call.

The code like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneString]];
```

However,iOS will show a alertView first, and make sure we want to call.

Can I directly open the call without showing a `UIAlerView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "tel:" scheme. Please see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html